# Reference vs. Bin folder in VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I used to add my ASP.NET dependencies added as a 'Reference' in my project, and also added them manually to the '/bin' folder. This seemed a bit redundant, as so I removed everything from the bin folder. The project compiled and runs, but VS2010 started to act funny now. It doesn't recognized a lot of my controls (eg. Telerik UI) and therefore a lot of HTML is underlined as an error. So is this because I really need to add my files as both dependencies and into /bin, or a different problem?

Comment: Where is the location, from you referencing them files?

Comment: AFAIR they will be copied to your target output folder, if you build the solution .

Answer (score 2):

Try to make a complete rebuild for your sollution.

Comment: This happens all the time, regardless of a rebuild/reboot/restart of the PC. Is there something to clean out VS2010 and .NET4.0, in case it's a caching problem of old configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Select properties on the referenced assemblies and check "copy local". This will copy the files to the /bin folder on compile.

Assemblies installed in the GAC will not need to be copied to the bin folder though. If you plan to deploy your solution to another machine, consider what assemblies are on your development machines GAC but not on the live/deployed server (and then either install them to the GAC on the live server or have vs copy to the bin by selecting copy local)